# Using CASE where need data from another record

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm using a CASE statement in a SELECT statement that arguably should be broken up into smaller parts but I'm one field off completing this task and have passed the point of no return.

Without dropping the whole query in here, the gist of the issue is this:

```
SELECT
    Dogs,
    Cats,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN my.my_id = 2765 THEN my.data END) AS CountAccounts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3347 THEN my.data END) AS CountUpgradedAccounts
```

`my` refers to a table that is a lookup table of name value pairs. When my.my_id = 3347 that signifies an "upgraded" account and the data point is the date that the account was upgraded. When my.my_id = 2765 that signifies account creation and the corresponding data point is the accountID.

`my` It looks like this:

```
UserID | my_id | Data
374    | 2765  | 8826
487    | 3347  | 2013-09-01
662    | 2765  | 8826
321    | 2765  | 9213
722    | 3347  | 2014-10-14
852    | 2765  | 8826
487    | 2765  | 9213
```

When my_id = 2765, I'd like the distinct number of accountIDs that it relates to. In the table above that is 2: Accounts 8826 and 9213.

I know this would be really simple if I was pulling data from `my` only. But `my` is woven into my query in a way that complicates things.

In fact, here is the query, perhaps the problem will be easier to see. Note the last field being selected in the SELECT statement is the problem. I don;t want to count distinct dates, I want to count distinct accountIDs that have upgraded.:

```
SELECT 
    sub.name AS ARName,
    sub.desc AS ARDescription,
    m.name AS MessageName,
    m.subj AS MessageDescription,
    clk.type AS EventType,
    COUNT(DISTINCT clk.eid) AS CountAdmins,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3347 THEN clk.eid END) AS CountUpgradeAdmins,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN my.my_id = 2765 THEN my.data END) AS CountAccounts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3347 THEN my.data END) AS CountUpgradedAccounts # <-- THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
FROM
    bata.sseq seq 
INNER JOIN bata.messages m 
    ON m.id = seq.mid 
INNER JOIN bm_arc.clicks208 clk 
    ON clk.camp = seq.camp 
INNER JOIN bemails.cid cid 
    ON cid.id = clk.eid 
INNER JOIN bonfig.sub
    ON sub.id = seq.sid
LEFT JOIN bemails.my208 my 
    ON cid.id = my.eid AND (my_id = 3347 OR my_id = 2765) # only return people who upgraded and accountIDs
WHERE 
    seq.cid = 208
AND
    sub.desc REGEXP '^Home pg free trail (A|B)' 
GROUP BY
    ARName,
    ARDescription,
    MessageName,
    MessageDescription,
    EventType
```

I've found trying to word this question challenging so sorry if what I'm asking is not clear. If there's any more info I can add let me know.

Following discussion, what I'm asking for in other words:

> "For each instance of 3347 get the corresponding instances of UserID
>   and with those UserIDs the count of distinct corresponding datapoints
>   in my.data WHERE my.my_id = 2765"

Comment: Do you have duplicate rows for `UserId`?

Comment: Yes there will be duplicate rows

Comment: Is UserID the unique users?  Why do you have a UserID and mention an accountID?  What signifies a user in your schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try changing the problem line to, select UserId, not data:

```
SELECT 
    sub.name AS ARName,
    sub.desc AS ARDescription,
    m.name AS MessageName,
    m.subj AS MessageDescription,
    clk.type AS EventType,
    COUNT(DISTINCT clk.eid) AS CountAdmins,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN my.my_id = 3347 THEN clk.eid END) AS CountUpgradeAdmins,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN my.my_id = 2765 THEN my.data END) AS CountAccounts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT  my2.data ) AS CountUpgradedAccounts 
FROM
    bata.sseq seq 
INNER JOIN bata.messages m 
    ON m.id = seq.mid 
INNER JOIN bm_arc.clicks208 clk 
    ON clk.camp = seq.camp 
INNER JOIN bemails.cid cid 
    ON cid.id = clk.eid 
INNER JOIN bonfig.sub
    ON sub.id = seq.sid
LEFT JOIN bemails.my208 my 
    ON cid.id = my.eid AND (my.my_id = 3347 OR my.my_id = 2765) # only return people who upgraded and     

LEFT JOIN bemails.my208 my2 
    ON  my2.my_id = 2765 and my2.userID = my.userID and my.my_id=3347 #get the accounts that the user belongs to
WHERE 
    seq.cid = 208
    AND
    sub.desc REGEXP '^Home pg free trail (A|B)' 
GROUP BY
    ARName,
    ARDescription,
    MessageName,
    MessageDescription,
    EventType
```

Comment: Dan, thanks for answering but that will not work. I should have made it clearer in my question but a user and an account are two different things: an account can have multiple users. So, I need the distinct number of accounts. Am I making sense?

Comment: Can a user have multiple accounts?  How can you go from my.UserID to accountID?  However you do this, is what you want to take the count DISTINCT of

Comment: Correct, a user can have multiple accounts and an account can have multiple users. Basically it's a software product where many people (users) can access the same instance (the account). Yup, I imagine DISTINCT will be used at some point for this

Comment: if your view `my` looks only like `487    | 3347  | 2013-09-01` then you are only have the user and are missing the account information.  If you can't go from that information to accountID there is no way to count distinct accounts....

Comment: The account information is in another record. For the record you mentioned for user 487, the account is 9213. Have updated table in question to highlight. Make sense?

Comment: Didn't you say a user can have multiple accounts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63523/discussion-between-doug-firr-and-dan).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, creating 2 joins out of table 'my' and aligning on user ID did the trick.